After lightning and thunderstorm my STM32 chip got damaged
My STM32 breakout board was connected to a 15 V power supply which was then stepped down to 3.3 V by a buck converter.
After lightning and thunderstorm, the STM32 MCU got damaged but the buck converter worked fine. My laptop and phone were also plugged in but they did not get damaged.
I tested the board using stlink utility and when I tried to connect an error message appeared stating that the reset pin had been permanently pulled low.
Initially I had programmed the mcu to blink an led with the pc13 pin. After the strike the led was permanently on.
When I tried programming it it said no device found.
Kindly explain why this happened and help me solve this issue.

What else was the STM32 board connected to? You have claimed a correlation, but did anything else happen that could be related? Did you reverse the power supply or spill a cup of coffee on the board?

Nothing else was correlated

What else was the STM32 board connected to?

how do you know that it is damaged? ... how do you know that the other items are not damaged?

I had programmed it to blink an led. Afterward the led remained fully one meaning that the pin was permanently pulled low. While trying to see to connecting it to stlink utility, there was an error message stating that the reset pin was pulled low.

Nothing else was connected to the stm32 board

Your question cannot be answered.  All we can do is speculate.

From PS to LED, have there been any connections of considerable length/enclosed area? (You did power cycle the setup, and the problem persists?)

You should use TVSs and GDTs to protect your circuits from transients like this situation. Also you need proper grounding and may be use of Metal Oxide Varistors too according to your requirements.

One possibility is that there was a transient with high common-mode voltage on the mains and that was coupled through capacitance in the 15V switching supply and through the non-isolated buck converter to the board.
Then it would only take some path to ground through the MCU to damage the chip, either a connection or a spark.

How can I avoid this

@p_karis Unplug bench circuits from mains when you're not working with them/using them.

Make the circuit more like that in the laptop and phone, which probably means a better 15V supply and/or more protection between the STM32 and outside world.
